# Rails with devise, not redirect after log in at first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, redirect, devise

When login in at first time(just open brower), redirecting after login is not working.
but after that, refresh the page and login again then redirecting is worked!

Scenario:

1. Open the browser like Chrome
2. Go to localhost:3000/
3. Try to login
4. Just show processing message in , and not redirect
5. Refresh page(logged state)
6. Logout
7. Try to login again
8. Redirecting is working properly in this time.
9. After that, redirecting is perfectly working.

I checked Network pannel of developer tools.

When fail to redirect after login, Http Response is weird.
[image]

When success to redirect after login, Http Response is this.
[image]

Please someone tell me what is the problem....

**UPDATE --------------**

Follow is LOG in Rails

```
{"message":"Started POST \"/users/sign_in\" for ::1 at 2020-02-06 16:19:39 +0900","log.level":"INFO","timestamp":1580973579.0653708}

{"message":"Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML","log.level":"INFO","timestamp":1580973579.082703}

{"message":"  Parameters: {\"authenticity_token\"=>\"wdmq/LDDiGJGXAdONS2RrYIflNwLn1dUnIHKr+GDkXLvE7xrZt7ptkRldAtUb6/TsMyZS8FqoTGbKXk4c7uDWw==\", \"os_type\"=>\"\", \"device_key\"=>\"\", \"user\"=>{\"login_id\"=>\"test\", \"password\"=>\"[FILTERED]\", \"remember_me\"=>\"0\"}, \"commit\"=>\"로그인\"}","log.level":"INFO","timestamp":1580973579.082936}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[36mUser Load (1.0ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[34mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`login_id` = 'test' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.0854762}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[35m (0.2ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[35mBEGIN\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.1425989}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[36mLoginActivity Create (0.4ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[32mINSERT INTO `login_activities` (`scope`, `strategy`, `identity`, `success`, `user_type`, `user_id`, `context`, `ip`, `user_agent`, `referrer`, `created_at`) VALUES ('user', 'database_authenticatable', 'test@test.com', TRUE, 'User', 1137, 'users/sessions#create', '::1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36', 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', '2020-02-06 07:19:39')\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.143883}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[35m (0.6ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[35mCOMMIT\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.1452632}

{"message":"[ActiveJob] Enqueued AuthTrail::GeocodeJob (Job ID: aff35661-3812-4fc4-a0cc-4223862c8e6e) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fb27caa8468 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://plus/LoginActivity/31597>>","log.level":"INFO","timestamp":1580973579.146951}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[35m (0.1ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[35mBEGIN\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.148587}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[36mUser Update (0.3ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[33mUPDATE `users` SET `users`.`sign_in_count` = 248, `users`.`current_sign_in_at` = '2020-02-06 07:19:39', `users`.`last_sign_in_at` = '2020-02-06 07:19:24', `users`.`updated_at` = '2020-02-06 07:19:39' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1137\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.1495512}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[35m (0.4ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[35mCOMMIT\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.151389}

{"message":"ensure_primary_database sessions create","log.level":"WARN","timestamp":1580973579.152593}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[36mLoginActivity Load (0.7ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[34mSELECT `login_activities`.* FROM `login_activities` WHERE `login_activities`.`user_id` = 1137 AND `login_activities`.`user_type` = 'User' ORDER BY `login_activities`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.1545558}

{"message":"  \u001b[1m\u001b[36mCACHE LoginActivity Load (0.0ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1m\u001b[34mSELECT `login_activities`.* FROM `login_activities` WHERE `login_activities`.`user_id` = 1137 AND `login_activities`.`user_type` = 'User' ORDER BY `login_activities`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1\u001b[0m","log.level":"DEBUG","timestamp":1580973579.155754}

**{"message":"Redirected to http://localhost:3000/","log.level":"INFO","timestamp":1580973579.157964}
{"message":"Completed 302 Found in 76ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms | Allocations: 15600)\n\n","log.level":"INFO","timestamp":1580973579.158774}**
```

After this, site is freezing(processing request...) so there is no logs.

Comment: What is shown in logs?

Comment: @romnoks Ok, I add logs to the question.

Comment: `SELECT login_activities` hints that this is not just a vanilla Devise setup. Where is this coming from? Could it be responsible?

Comment: Whats inside the controller in authenticate_user?

Comment: @user2731985 did you figure this out? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late for you, but for anyone else having the same issue. this has to do with turbolinks.
adding `remote: true` to your app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb `form_for`

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class:"form-signin"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Solved it for me.